# For non-header-only libararies, and those who explicit instantiate templates, does it mean C++20's concept is useless?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

So C++20 Introduces a new thing called concept, which from what I see is used to constrain types of data that could be put into a template. So for a function, I could require that data that's fed in to like, must have a member `::inner`, or something like that.

Which to me, it's like making sure whose using that function couldn't just put whatever they like into the argument. But doesn't explicit instantiation already doing the same stuff? Like if I wrote a function library, and I didn't directly wrote the implementation directly into header files, but rather wrote it in a separate `.cpp` file and also explicit instantiate them. Doesn't such approach defeats the usage of `concept`? As if me, the developer, is instantiate some data types to some function, I'm already guaranteeing that it'll work as expected when fed into the function's argument. And if I didn't instantiate a function for a class, then you simply couldn't call it.

In such case, is there any reason for me to implement concept? Except that it seems C++20's concept error is more clear than the error you'll receive without concept.

Comment: If you explicitly instantiate them the end-user will not feel any real benefit of `concept`s but I personally think doing so is generally not good software design. Furthermore the introduction of C++20 `module`s (as opposed to traditional header and source files) will change this also quite a bit. With `concept`s the error messages are more clear and the code becomes more expressive. The only way of encapsulating this so far have been constructs like `std::enable_if` which are often quite hard to read.

Comment: Constraints can also be used to help control function overload resolution and partial class template specialization selection, which could be useful even if all template instantiations will be explicit.

Comment: " it seems C++20's concept error is more clear than the error you'll receive without concept." - AFAIC that's pretty much the whole point of the `concepts` concept, as opposed to relying on comments to document the restrictions applicable to a template.

Comment: *"concept error is more clear than the error you'll receive without concept"* - You haven't had a chance to see the errors standard library implementations produce **with** concepts, have you? It's... not a whole lot clearer. If library components re-use eachother and then you violate a concept only in some internal call you get the exact same wall of text we get today. "Clear errors" is not a guarantee with concepts. It's only "possible", and therefore not the whole point of concepts.

Answer (score 3):

I'm setting aside the design choice of using templates only to explicitly instantiate everything. Maybe you need that maybe you don't, but concepts is a valuable tool regardless.

First of all a **well defined concept** will provide **"in-code" documentation** of what the characteristics of expected types are. If you instantiate something with `int` and `Duck`, it's not going to be clear what an `int` and a `Duck` have in common to be able to use the same template. Whereas if they were sharing for example the `copyable` concept **it becomes apparent what instantiations have in common** or why the generalization was made.

Secondly your library might need **extensions** (I mean if it's not dead code, it will need amending of some sort sooner or later). By expressing the type requirements, **you communicate not only restrictions but intent as well**; this is extremely valueable for code extensibility.

Lastly it **makes your design process clear(er)**. If you're using templates in the first place, it is a good practice to be able to formally verify your type system, predict connections and dead ends and put some extra thought on what you actually want to generalize over. An amazing example of how concepts benefit this process, can be seen with [named requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req). The Standards committee put a tremendous effort into formalizing the properties of types when defining standard library facilities so e.g. an algorithm may be defined on [Containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) of [Trivially Copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) elements. Up until concepts, the burden of verifying and checking those types fell on the developer, since there was no formal way of expressing those requirements; now we're transitioning to concepts making the definition and checking of such properties a formal process, backed by the core language.

In support of the 2nd & 3rd points consider [SFINAE techniques vs concepts](https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2019/10/04/concepts-versus-sfinae-based-constraints/). **Using templates is much more than what you expose in an interface**, so your library may internally rely on type restrictions to choose the correct compilation path. This process is cleanly defined with concepts, whereas legacy approaches tend to overcrowd your code.